# Recursive tree search: Spawning concurrent workers with side effect

Tags: clojure

I am currently working on a tree search algorithm to walk the optimal, cost efficient path through a tree structure.

```
(def tree 
         '([1]
          [3 5]
         [5 6 4]
        [2 3 4 5]))
```

The function initiates multiple "workers" through a recursive function call, each time a new node is reached.

```
(defn treewalk [tree]
       (let [worker_history {}]
       (letfn [(get-neighbours [level current_position]
                               (;; get adjacent nodes one level below)
                (worker [current_level current_position cost individual_history]
                        (if (;; current level above bottom)
                            (let [neighbours (get-neighbours  current_level current_position)]
                            ;; recursive worker call for next 2 branches
                            (worker (+ level1 1) (first_neighbour) (+ cost (current_cost)) 
                               (;; updated individual_history))
                            (worker (+ level1 1) (second neighbour) (+ cost (current_cost)) 
                                (;; updated individual_history)))
                                 ;; else: worker at bottom -> insert cost and individual history into worker_history
                            (assoc worker_history cost individual_history))
                                 )))))
```

The worker_history map is supposed to store the costs and individual paths and is updated with these values when each individual worker reaches bottom of the tree structure. I am aware that working with these sides effects is not the most elegant way to approach that problem in Clojure!

Currently, I am running into the problem that `worker_history` only returns ine entry of the very last worker that has finished and does not behave as a static variable within the function scope, so there is no concurrent access of that ofject. How could I still modify my approach in order to achieve this level of "concurrency"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure isn't tree. In functional languages, trees are usually written as nested lists (or vectors), like this: `'(3 (4) (5))` or this `'(3 (4 (2) (8)) (5))`. If I stick to your instructions *recursive tree search, return costs and paths for all workers*, this should work:

```
(defn tree-costs [tree]
  (let [worker-history (atom [])]
    (letfn [(treewalk [tree cost history]
              (if (= (count tree) 1) (swap! worker-history
                                            conj [(+ (first tree) cost)
                                                  (conj history (first tree))])
                                     (doseq [node (rest tree)]
                                       (treewalk node
                                                 (+ cost (first tree))
                                                 (conj history (first tree))))))]
      (treewalk tree 0 [])
      @worker-history
      )))

(tree-costs '(3 (4) (5))) => [[7 [3 4]] [8 [3 5]]]
(tree-costs '(3 (4 (2) (8)) (5))) => [[9 [3 4 2]] [15 [3 4 8]] [8 [3 5]]]
```

Also check [clojure.core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/) for thread concurrency.

Comment: Thank you! I will investigate that further. I did not yet get that far on my Clojure Journey.

Answer (score 2):

In order to update `worker_hisoty` concurently, you can try [atom](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom)

```
...
  (let [worker_history (atom {})]
...
```

then update it with [swap!](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap!)

```
...
            (swap! worker_history assoc cost individual_history)
...
```

Simplistically you think about atom as a global mutable variable with atomic updates

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of Atom! That is exactly what I was looking for...

Answer (score 2):

I would caution against using stateful techniques as you miss out on the benefits of pure functions. Without knowing the full context of the problem you are trying to solve I cannot say if using `atom` will serve you well.

Rather than update an `atom` for each tree path, a map can be constructed using `reduce`:

```clj
(defn paths [tree]
  (when-let [root (ffirst tree)]
    (if-let [r (next tree)]
      (let [left (paths r)
            right (paths (map rest r))]
        (map #(cons root %) (concat left right)))
      [[root]])))

(defn tree-costs [tree]
  (reduce (fn [m path] (update m (reduce + path) (fnil conj #{}) path))
          {}
          (paths tree)))
```

Comment: Absolutely, I asked this question out of curiosity if a stateful solution is feasable in Clojure. There wer still some Node.JS patterns in the back of my head... However, after approaching the problem a second time, I would also go for a pure functional approach without the side effects.

Comment: Another FP convert! ^u^